# How to update realm data when moving data in swift?

Tags: swift, realm

When moving the position of the cell in the table view, the data of the realm is also updated.

I did the following as I did on Android, but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

```
func updateMoveData(title:String, listId:Int, id:Int, icon:Int)
{
    let realm = try! Realm()
    
    let getDbData = realm.object(ofType: MainListRealm.self, forPrimaryKey: id)

    try! realm.write {
        getDbData?.title = title
        getDbData?.listId = listId
        getDbData?.icon = icon
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {
    
    let tempstart: Int = to.row
    let tempend: Int = fromIndexPath.row
    let from: Int = to.row
    let too: Int = fromIndexPath.row
    
    if from < too {

        updateMoveData(title: mDataSet![tempend].title, listId: mDataSet![tempend].listId, id: mDataSet![tempstart].id, icon: mDataSet![tempend].icon)
        for i in from...too-1 {
            //print("i = \(i)")
            updateMoveData(title: mDataSet![i].title, listId: mDataSet![i].listId, id: mDataSet![i+1].id, icon: mDataSet![i].icon)
        }

    } else if from > too {

        updateMoveData(title: mDataSet![tempend].title, listId: mDataSet![tempend].listId, id: mDataSet![tempstart].id, icon: mDataSet![tempend].icon)
        //for i in from...too+1 {
        for i in (too+1...from).reversed() {
            //print("i = \(i)")
             updateMoveData(title: mDataSet![i].title, listId: mDataSet![i].listId, id: mDataSet![i-1].id, icon: mDataSet![i].icon)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear - the code in your question writes data to realm when the cell is moved but you're asking how to update realm when moving data? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Sorry for the question is not clear
When I move the table view by dragging, I also want to move the realm db data.
Thank you

Comment: When you say 'move', what does 'move' mean? Realm objects are not necessarily ordered. The only ordering would be if an object is referred to in a List object (which has a guaranteed order) or you incorporate some form of sort on a Results object - by date for example. We don't have that information nor know what your Realm objects look like. It also appears you're just overwriting the properties (title, etc) of an existing object which doesn't 'move' anything. You're going to need to greatly clarify the question and include your objects so we understand what you're attempting.